# Inverse of $I +T^*T$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to show that the inverse of the operator $I +T^*T$ exists.

What I have been trying to do is trial and error taking inverses of $T$ and $T^*$ but to no avail.

Comment: What context, a Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes @copper.hat in a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $T$ is bounded. Then
$$
            \|x\|^{2}+\|Tx\|^{2}=((I+T^{\star}T)x,x) \le \|(I+T^{\star}T)x\|\|x\| \\
              \|x\|^{2} \le \|(I+T^{\star}T)x\|\|x\| \\
                     \|x\| \le \|(I+T^{\star}T)x\|.
$$
The last inequality can be use to show that the range of $I+T^{\star}T$ is closed, and $I+T^{\star}T$ has a bounded inverse on its range. To see that $I+T^{\star}T$ is surjective, note that
$$
           \mathcal{R}(I+T^{\star}T)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(I+T^{\star}T)=\{0\}.
$$

Comment: Isn't the $\mathcal{R} (I+T^*T)^ += \mathcal{N}(I+T^*T)^*$?

Comment: I am thinking that since $T^*T$ is self-adjoint and hence normal, so must $I + T^*T$. Then it is enough to stop at your last inequality.

Comment: @Maria : Yes, $T^{\star}T=(T^{\star}T)^{\star}$. And don't forget that $\mathcal{R}(I+T^{\star}T)=\mathcal{N}(I+T^{\star}T)^{\perp}$ because the range of $I+T^{\star}T$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T^*T$ is Hermitian, the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are real. Suppose $v_i$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray} \langle \lambda_i v_i, v_i\rangle =\langle T^*Tv_i, v_i\rangle= \|Tv_i\|^2\geq 0 \end{eqnarray}
The eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $T^*T$ are real and nonnegative, and the eigenvalues of $I+T^*T$ are $1+\lambda_i$, which are nonzero.

Comment: It may not be so simple if the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional and $T$ isn't compact.  Spectral theory will still provide an inverse (provided $T$ is bounded) but there may not be any eigenvectors.